# toast message is not displaying on some profiles

Tags: quickaction, toast

I created quick actions that will check some criteria and display toast messages accordingly. It is working fine for system admin and some non-sys admin profiles, but failing on some other custom profiles. Is that something related to access and privileges or roles and permissions?

Comment: I suggest you check for errors in the JavaScript console and in Apex debug logs too if Apex is involved; yes likely that a permission problem is causing the code to fail before the toast event is dispatched.

Comment: Sure, @KeithC. I will start debugging the issue as per your suggestion and get back to you. Thanks